# Why can't java generics be in arrays?

Tags: java, language-design, generics

Why is it that when I try to make an array of ArrayLists: `ArrayList<Integer>[] arr=new ArrayList<Integer>[40];` there is an error and java does not allow this?

Is there a reason related to java's implementation of generics, generics in any language, or something arbitrary?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7810241/1029272 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483800/creating-an-array-of-generic-collections

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is one of major holes in Java's generics, arrays are [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), meaning that an array of type `Foo[]` is a subclass of `Object[]` and `ParentOfFoo[]`. Contrast this with `List<Foo>` which doesn't have this behavior.

This was important when Java didn't have generics (until Java 5) because otherwise, something like a generic sorting function was just impossible.

However it has this tricky problem that [arrays like to know what type they are at runtime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html). However generics in Java is based on type erasure. These two things don't mesh well at all and that's where we get our problem.

So the long and short of it is, in Java 1, covariant arrays partially filled the hole that a lack of generics created. However when they tried to properly fill this hole, backwards compatibility meant that arrays were pretty impossible to implement.

In fact, the guy who actually created the framework for generics, Martin Odersky, talked about this [here](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/origins_of_scala.html) during an interview about why he made Scala. (Pretty fascinating if you are interested in Scala's history at all)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason related to java's implementation of generics, generics in any language, or something arbitrary?

Actually, it's somewhat arbitrary.

The problem is that it allows a hole in the type system, since `ArrayList<T>[]` can be casted to `Object[]` and then you can put an `ArrayList<U>` in the array, where `U != T`.

Java designers decided to block this hole as eagerly as possible, by not allowing `new ArrayList<T>[N]` at all.

However, it could also have been plugged by not allowing upcasting of arrays of generics (without an "unchecked" warning).

Comment: This answer is underrated. Very simple and doesn't use jargon on vague terms. Thanks very much.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on why this is different to the case where you put an `Integer` into an `Object[]` that's actually a `String[]`

Answer (score -3):

because the **array is covariant** which every type is a subclass of the object so this gives an error in run time due to casting exception. while the **generic is invariant** so when it builds on the type ensure or type-safe so if the type not like it creates type it gives a compiler error.